# Can't access JSON object properties

Tags: javascript, json

I am receiving back from the server a JSON string like this one:

```
[{"Title":"Windows","URL":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/soft\/","Type":"out","Price":"140"}]
```

I save it into a variable `string`and I am trying to convert it to a JSON object like this:

```
var json = JSON.parse(string);
```

after that I get the Object which looks great:

```
[Object]
   ->Price: "140"
   ->Title: "Windows"
   ->Type: "out"
   ->URL: "http:www.domain.com/soft/"
   ->__proto__: Object
```

but when I try to acces it using for example `json.Price` I get `undefined`, any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: Please post a small example that reproduces the problem. Chances are you simply have a typo or mis-assigned variable somewhere.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you wrap your content with [] you get an array with one object. So this should work:

```
json[0].Price
```

But you can also remove the brackets.

Comment: [Well there's your problem](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09eP8xjsrco)